# Evaluate the following complex integral $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{\overline{f(z)}}{z-a}\,dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let , $f$ be analytic for $|z|<2$. Show that $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{\overline{f(z)}}{z-a}\,dz=\begin{cases}\overline{f(0)} &\text{ if } |a|<1\\\overline{f(0)}-\overline{f(1/a)}&\text{ if }|a|>1\end{cases}$$

By putting $z=e^{i\theta}$ , $\displaystyle\int_{|z|=1}\frac{\overline{f(z)}}{z-a}\,dz=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\overline{f(e^{i\theta})}}{e^{i\theta}-a}ie^{i\theta}\,d\theta=i\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\overline{f\left(\overline{e^{-i\theta}}\right)}}{1-ae^{-i\theta}}\,d\theta$.

Now putting , $e^{-i\theta}=t$ , it becomes $\displaystyle =-\int_{|t|=1}\frac{\overline{f(\bar t)}}{1-at}\,dt$. As $f(t)$ is analytic so $\overline{f(\bar t)}$ is also analytic. Now we can apply the residue theorem and finally I got the desire integral $=-\overline{f(0)}$ when $|a|<1$.

> My problem is about the **sign**. I got an extra negative sign. Please verify my proof & detect where I made mistake ...

Comment: When I do the usual substitution $z = e^{it}$, then substitute $s = -t$ and then go back, I get that the integral is equal to $\frac 1 a\int_{|z|=1}\frac{h(z)}{z}\,dz$, where$$h(z) = \frac{\overline{f(\overline z)}}{a^{-1}-z}.$$ Hence, if $|a| < 1$, $h$ is analytic in a neighborhood of the closed unit disc and so, the original expression is equal to $h(0)/a = \overline{f(0)}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\overline{ f(z)}}{z-a}\,dz&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\overline{  f(e^{i\theta})}}{e^{i\theta}-a}ie^{i\theta}\,d\theta \tag 1\\\\
&=\int_{0}^{-2\pi}\frac{\overline{  f(e^{-i\theta})}}{e^{-i\theta}-a}ie^{-i\theta}\,(-1)\,d\theta \tag 2\\\\
&=\int_{-2\pi}^{0}\frac{\overline{  f(\overline{e^{i\theta}})}}{\left(e^{-i\theta}-a\right)e^{i2\theta}}ie^{i\theta}\,d\theta \tag 3\\\\
&=-\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\overline{  f(\overline{e^{i\theta}})}}{\left(ae^{i\theta}-1\right)e^{i\theta}}ie^{i\theta}\,d\theta \tag 4\\\\ 
&=-\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\overline{f(\overline{z})}}{z(az-1)}\,dz \tag 5\\\\
&=\oint_{|z|=1}\overline{f(\overline{z})}\left(\frac{1}{z}-\frac{a}{az-1}\right)\,dz \tag 6\\\\
&=2\pi i
\begin{cases}
\overline{f(0)}&,|a|<1\\\\
\overline{f(0)}-\overline{f(\overline{1/a})}&,|a|>1 \tag 7
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

In arriving at $(1)$, we parametrized the unit circle letting $z=e^{i\theta}$.

In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we enforced the substitution $\theta \to -\theta$.

In going from $(2)$ to $(3)$, we absorbed the factor of $-1$ by transposing the integration limits.  We wrote $e^{-i\theta}=\overline{e^{i\theta}}$ in the argument of $f$. And we multiplied the numerator and denominator by $e^{i2\theta}$.

In going from $(3)$ to $(4)$, we multiplied $\left(e^{-i\theta}-a\right)e^{i\theta}=-(ae^{i\theta}-1)$ and then exploited the $2\pi$-periodicity of the integrand to transform the limits from $-2\pi$ to $0$ to $0$ to $2\pi$.

In going from $(4)$ to $(5)$, we moved from a parametric description back to the contour integral representation.

In going from $(5)$ to $(6)$, we used partial fraction expansion.

And in going from $(6)$ to $(7)$, we used the residue theorem.

Comment: Yes..I realize my mistake..But I can't understand your 3rd line to 4th line. How $\displaystyle \int_{-2\pi}^0=-\int_0^{2\pi}$ ?

Comment: The integrand is $2\pi$-periodic

Comment: From 1st line to 2nd line you put $z=e^{i\theta}$. But how you get from 2nd line to 3rd ? How $\int_0^{2\pi}$ transformed into $\int_0^{-2\pi}$ ?

Comment: From the second to third line, we absorbed the factor $(-1)$ by transposing the limits of integration.  From the first to the second line, we enforced the substitution $\theta \to -\theta$.

Comment: I've edited to provide a line-by-line explanation of the steps in the development.  Again, I really want to give you the best answer I can.  So, please just let me know how I can improve my answer.  -Mark

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  -Mark

Comment: @MarkViola Is there a way for one get from step 6 to 7 without use of the residue theorem?

Comment: @mathwolf What did you have in mind.

Comment: @MarkViola I've been given this Q and in a previous part of the Q I proved that for a continuous function $\phi:A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ and $\gamma$ as above,
$$\overline{\int_{\gamma}\phi(z)\,\, dz} = -\int_{\gamma} \overline{\phi(z)}\,\,\frac{dz}{z^2}$$
Then, using this (and CIF) I've managed to get the following:
$$\overline{\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z}dz}\,\,-\,\,\overline{\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z-1/\bar{a}}dz}$$ which by CIF is equal to $\overline{f(0)}-\overline{f(1/\bar{a})}$ . Now I just don't know how to get the other case.

Comment: @MarkViola I ask for a method without the residue theorem as we have yet to cover it.

Comment: From CIF, the second integral is $0$ for $|a|<1$.

Comment: @MarkViola So, CIF states that:
Let U be a domain. Let $\gamma$ be a positively
oriented, simple closed contour with its image and interior lying entirely within U.
Suppose that $a$ is a point in the interior of $\gamma$. If f is holomorphic on U, then
$$f(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z-a}\,dz$$
I understand that as $|a|<1\,\, ,1/|\bar{a}| >1$ then $1/\bar{a}$ is not in the interior of $\gamma$ which means CIF can't be applied. But I don't understand how this translates to the integral being $0$. What am I missing here?

Comment: @MarkViola Just following up in case you didn't get a notification for my previous comment.

Comment: @mathwolf If $|a|>1$he integrand is analytic for $|z|\le 1$.  Cauchy's Integral Theorem guarantees that the integral over $\gamma$ is zero.

Comment: @MarkViola Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.